# What's the use case for GitLab CI's `dependencies`?

Tags: gitlab-ci

GitLab CI has the concept of [`dependencies`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies), which "should be used in conjunction with artifacts and allows you to define the artifacts to pass between different jobs".

However, "`artifacts` from all previous stages are passed by default". Which leads me to conclude that you only need to use `dependencies` when needing to pass artifacts between jobs in the same or later stages. However, "an error will be shown if you define jobs from the current stage or next ones."

So if it need not be used for previous stages, and cannot be used for anything other than previous stages, when *would* you use `dependencies`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> artifacts from all previous stages are passed by default

Means just that. By default you get all the dependencies. However there are times when you don't want all of them. For example if the last step in your pipe is sending a notification to slackchat you don't want to download hundreds of megabytes of artifacts just to do that.

Comment: Ah right, so does that mean that by specifying `dependencies` I am actually signalling that I want _fewer_ artifacts?

Comment: @Vincent Exactly.

Comment: Reviving this thread,

I have a parent and multi project child pipeline. Parent pipeline has the artifact repo1/path1/file1.yml.

How do I access this file from the multi project child pipeline? The current dir in this child pipeline stage is repo2 and I could not find the path repo1/path1/file1.yml in this job. Could you please advise?